# How o set MAC address in WAR file

Tags: java, jsp, war

Here's a use case:

A user visits my website and fills the registration form, then we capture the user IP address, the MAC address, OS version, and host name. A WAR file is directly sent to the user based on the user's email address provided in the registration form. The user then downloads this WAR file and deploys it.

My problem is when that the downloaded WAR runs, it only captures the IP address, MAC address, host name, OS version (user ) in user's side (client-side). If these particular values don't match, the WAR file is not deployed in the client-side.

Comment: I think you have to re-design that way of identifying users. Your current one will encounter problems with common network technologies like routers, NAT, proxies...

Comment: Anders Lindahl : Can you tell me any suggestions for this question?

Comment: *Why* are you capturing the MAC address? Are you aware that you are almost certainly only capturing the MAC address of the nearest router or proxy? Are you aware that MAC addresses can be changed by the user?